# Issue with LCMM Plot Code (invalid subscript type 'list')

Tags: r

I'm attempting to follow a tutorial (link here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/latent-class-mixed-models-with-graphics/) for running a latent class mixture model. My model has run properly, but i'm having an issue plotting the latent classes.

```
Con2 < lcmm(ConT~AdminCount,random=~AdminCount,subject='PID',mixture=~AdminCount,ng=3,idiag=TRUE,data=datal,link="linear")
summary(Con2) 

datal$CONid <- as.character(datal$PID)
people3 <- as.data.frame(Con2$pprob[1:2])
datal$CONgroup <- character(people3$class[sapply(datal$CONid, function(x) which(people3$CONid==x))])
```

When I try to run the last line of code, I get this error:

> Error in people3$class[sapply(datal$CONid, function(x)
>   which(people3$CONid ==  :    invalid subscript type 'list'

Any ideas what this error means/how I can address it?

**Pictures here of all my code and output:**

[info about variables being used in model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9LuY.png)

[Probability values from model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGaSb.png)

[Model Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlmJy.png)

[Graph Code and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nQ2q.png)

Comment: the link just goes to plain r-bloggers and none of us can reproduce your code nor your error

Comment: Even if you are basing your question off a tutorial found at an external link, it would be very helpful if you could provide a complete example that allows people to reproduce the error you got, so they can help you fix it! See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, Max and qdread! This is my first stack overflow post, so I appreciate your help w/ question etiquette. 

I updated my post to include info about my data and code (as well as errors). Hope this helps clarify!

Answer (score 0):

We still can't recreate your error; I did find the [original tutorial posting](https://mcfromnz.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/latent-class-mixture-modeling-with-graphics/) though as well as the [full R code](https://github.com/nzcoops/blog_code/blob/master/2017-07-20_lcmmBlogCode.R) and the [data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nzcoops/blog_code/master/lcmmBlogData.csv).

So I need to guess your error. Note that the error statement is that the "subscript is a list". The *subscript* is the function call `sapply(datal$CONid, function(x) which(people3$CONid==x)`. In the default setting, the sapply-function will return a list, if the return values of the function are of irregular length (otherwise a vector or a matrix). That is, the elements of `datal$CONid` occur with irregular frequency among the entries of `people3$CONid`.

Hope you can work from here on.